# Java enhanced for loop multiple variables

Tags: java

Im trying to make an address book. Ive made one array with names, and one with numbers. But i want to get the names and the numbers displayed at the same row while using the enhanced for loop. Heres my code:

```
    public class AdressBook {
public static void main (String[] args){

    String[] names = {"Johnny", "Bob", "Bobby"};
    int[] numbers = {123, 1234, 12345};

    for(String name : names){
        System.out.println(name);
    }

}
```

}

Heres the output that i want to have:

```
Johnny 123
Bob 1234
Bobby 12345
```

And remember: i want to use the enhanced for loop!
Thanks for the help, it would mean a lot to me!

Comment: why do you want to use an enhanced for loop for 2 arrays? it doesnt work that way.

Comment: Use a class to aggregate the data or use a traditional for loop. You don't try to cut meat with a spoon either.

Answer (score 0):

Enhanced for loop is meant for looping an array or list without worrying about creating a temporay variable and with old for loop.

In this scenario you should use a map or you should crate a class with two properties in it.
ie AddressBookEntry

Answer (score -1):

```
 public class AdressBook {
  public static void main (String[] args){

   String[] names = {"Johnny", "Bob", "Bobby"};
   int[] numbers = {123, 1234, 12345};

   int i =0;
   for(String name : names){
     System.out.println(name +" "+numbers[i++]);
   }
}
```